# PHP OOP number of results

Tags: php, oop, numbers

Can someone tell me how to return the number of results if I use this function to grab data from the database? I have tried including this:

> $this->number = $result->num_rows;

But that didn't do the trick. Also, if anyone can give me some advice to do the below code in a better way, that would be helpful too.

```
<?php
    public function grabResults($table, $values = '*', $where = NULL, $field1 = NULL, $and = NULL, $field2 = NULL, $order = NULL)
    {
            $result = 'SELECT '.$values.' FROM '.$table;

            if($where != NULL)
        {
                $result = 'SELECT '.$values.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$field1.' = '.$where;
        }

            if($and != NULL)
        {
                $result = 'SELECT '.$values.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$field1.' = '.$where.' AND '.$field2.' = '.$and;
        }

            if($order != NULL)
        {

                $result = 'SELECT '.$values.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$field1.' = '.$where.' ORDER BY '.$order.' ASC';
        }

        $query = $this->data->mysqli->query($result);

        if($query)
        {
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
                return $rows;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This code is a bit terrifying, for a few security reasons.  If you actually need such an abstraction, have you considered an ORM?  Also, `mysqli`?  Are you sure you're using PDO?

Comment: I won't be using this code, it's for my personal learning purposes. Also, I never stated anywhere I am using PDO, and if I didm apologies :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the title.

Comment: Very scary looking code. It reminds me of my first employer `eval($_GET['id');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$result->num_rows;
```

sounds like a Codeigniter function that you tried to use in raw php.
Have you tried to count() the query?

```
$count=count($query);
```